# How to create the Global Privacy Platform(GPP) String

Tags: privacy, privacy-policy, iab

Global Privacy Platform(GPP) String is a way to communicate user privacy preferences to multiple vendors. [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/Global-Privacy-Platform/blob/main/Core/Consent%20String%20Specification.md#gpp-string-format)

I'm having trouble understanding the header, specifically the Section Range.
The first example in the documentation says:

Section Range

Amount = 000000000001

Item 1 Single = 0

Item 1 start ID = 011

Can anyone clarify how are they getting the 'Amount' and 'Item 1 Single' values?

I was not able to find too many resources on this topic. The resources that I found useful are [this github documentation](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/Global-Privacy-Platform) and [this powerpoint presentation](https://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/IABTechLab_MSPA_GPP_2022_12.pdf)

Also if this is the incorrect forum for this question, please guide me to the correct one. Thank you.